Why is my WPF Popup being scaled by parent transform?
I have a custom WPF UserControl containing a <Canvas>, which contains a <Popup> element. The custom control is scalable/resizable by the user, but I want the Popup element to appear at a fixed size/scale (relative to DPI, I guess) regardless of which transforms are applied to the parent Canvas element. Imagine a zoomable/draggable drawing interface, where you want the pop-ups to be legible regardless of zoom level.
Is this possible? I actually thought this was the default for <Popup> elements but it doesn't seem to be the case. They're being scaled along with the other contents of the parent <Canvas>. I'm not explicitly applying any scaling to the  children, just to the parent <Canvas> via a RenderTransform.

I was able to resolve this by creating the Popup programmatically in my code-behind, instead of creating it in XAML and placing inside the the element as a child.
